# 400 error with SalesForce CDP connector when filtering by date

Tags: salesforce, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

i'm facing a problem with SalesForce CDP connector query.
it works fine when i dont use a date filter:

[image]

result :

[image]

But it doesnt works when i filter on date:
[image]

Result:

**Message**: Request returned status code 400
**Error type**: SDC:BAD_REQUEST

i run the same query directly in SalesForce and it works fine.

Here is the result:
[image]

The date problem happens only in mulesoft cdp connector yet is the same query

How can if fix this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)